# Simple MVC API unable to get working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am new to MVC Web API. So please excuse me if something asked is very stupid.

I know its very basic question but I am not able to find the mistake I'm going.

This is my sqlserver db:

[image: enter code here]

This is my users model:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web

Namespace WebApi.Models
    Public Class users
        Public Property userid() As Guid
        Public Property logintype() As String
        Public Property username() As String
        Public Property password() As String
        Public Property email() As String
        Public Property createddate() As DateTime

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Now this is my usercontroller:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports MvcApplication1.WebApi.Models

Namespace WebApi.Controllers
    Public Class usercontroller
        Inherits ApiController
        Private Shared ReadOnly repository As New userdetails()
        Public Function GetAllUsers() As IEnumerable(Of users)
            Return repository.GetAll()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This is my userdetails model:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Namespace WebApi.Models
    Public Class userdetails
        Private users As New List(Of users)()
        Private con As SqlConnection
        Private da As SqlDataAdapter
        Private ds As New DataSet()

        Public Function GetAll() As IEnumerable(Of users)
            con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=UsersList;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password="****")
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from users", con)
            da.Fill(ds)
            For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                users.Add(New users() With {.userid = Guid.Parse(dr(0).ToString()), .logintype = Integer.Parse(dr(1).ToString()), .username = dr(2).ToString(), .password = dr(3).ToString(), .email = Integer.Parse(dr(4).ToString()), .createddate = DateTime.Parse(dr(5).ToString())})
            Next dr
            Return users
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Error is no clear, can you post it in text rather than image?

Comment: `.email = Integer.Parse(dr(4).ToString())` why are you parsing using `Integer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is wrong -

```
.email = Integer.Parse(dr(4).ToString())
.logintype = Integer.Parse(dr(1).ToString())
```

They are defined in the model as `string`, then why to type cast to `Integer`. So removing type casting and have it like shown below -

```
.email = dr(4).ToString()
.logintype = dr(1).ToString()
```